# Websphere 8.5 Log4J not working with Parent First

Tags: log4j, websphere, apache-commons-logging

I tried to deploy my application to Websphere 8.5. Due to some reasons, I need to use class loader Parent First.

This is my ear file structure

```
EAR
-|__META-INF
-|__WAR
-----|__META-INF
-----|-----|__MANIFEST
-----|-----|__services
-----|__WEB_INF (included compiled classes, lib, conf files etc.)
```

I have tried to put the `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` file in `META-INF/services` with value `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger` but it is not working.

Anyone know how to config log4j for Websphere 8.5?

Thanks

PS: I used log4j 1.2.17 and commons-logging 1.1.3

Comment: PARENT FIRST is the default, so you need to not change that, correct? (BTW, I'm having the same problem with 8.5 and JCL. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19946068/796761 )

Comment: To modify my previous comment, I'm now finding this technique working fine if I deploy log4j and JCL to the same location. Is this not true for you? (Mind you, I'm using log4j1.2.12 and JCL 1.0)

Comment: Do you have Log4J's JAR file, as well as `commons-logging` inside `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: @dbreaux: They are always in the same location